# accepts_nested_attributes_forで生えたメソッドとcreateやupdateの関係性

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[【Rails】fields_for と accepts_nested_attributes_for - kzy52's blog](http://kzy52.com/entry/2013/07/10/200144)

**引用：**

> accepts_nested_attributes_forです。すごく便利。
>   profile_attributes= と academics_attributes= メソッドが追加される
>
> **登録時**
>   params = { user: { name: 'Test', profile_attributes: { nickname: 'test' } } }
>   user = User.create(params[:user])
>   user.profile.id # => 1
>   ser.profile.nickname # => 'test'
>
> **更新時**
>   params = { user: { profile_attributes: { id: '1', nickname: 'test2' } } }
>   user = User.find 1
>   user.update params[:user]
>   user.profile.nickname # => 'test2'

**入れ子のForm**で使う`accepts_nested_attributes_for`ですが、
**末尾が=のメソッド**ができることがわかりました。

また**末尾が=のメソッド**の意味は、
[ruby on rails - Rubyのメソッド名の末尾に = (イコール) - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18114/ruby%e3%81%ae%e3%83%a1%e3%82%bd%e3%83%83%e3%83%89%e5%90%8d%e3%81%ae%e6%9c%ab%e5%b0%be%e3%81%ab-%e3%82%a4%e3%82%b3%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab)
に質問させていただきわかりました。

さて、上記引用の`create`と`update`ですが、**Hash**を与えているだけにすぎず、`accepts_nested_attributes_for`で生えた**末尾が=のメソッド**と関係性が頭の中でひも付きません。**Hash**を与えているだけに過ぎないのに**新しくメソッドを生やす意味**とはなんでしょうか？　またこのようなテクニックが簡単にわかる簡単なサンプルソースを付けていただけるとうれしいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### RoRでの似たような該当部分

`accepts_nested_attributes_for`とは若干ずれますが、
`*=`を使ったテクニックとしては下記が該当するでしょうか。
（ActiveModel::Modelの話なのでそう大きくはずれていない）

[Method: ActiveModel::Model#initialize — Documentation for rails (4.0.0)](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/ActiveModel%2FModel%3Ainitialize)

**File 'activemodel/lib/active_model/model.rb', line 78**

```
def initialize(params={})
  params.each do |attr, value|
    self.public_send("#{attr}=", value)
  end if params

  super()
end
```

### Hashでインスタンス変数をSETする例（自作する場合）

```
class Hoge
  attr_accessor :a, :b

  def initialize(params={})
    params.each do |attr, value|
      self.public_send("#{attr}=", value)
    end if params
  end
end

hoge = Hoge.new(a: "A", b:"B")
puts hoge.a
puts hoge.b
```

#### *=メソッドはないけどよいの？

`attr_accessor`のソースを読みに行くと、

```
# attr_accessor(symbol, ...)    -> nil
# attr_accessor(string, ...)    -> nil
#  
# Defines a named attribute for this module, where the name is
# <i>symbol.</i><code>id2name</code>, creating an instance variable
# (<code>@name</code>) and a corresponding access method to read it.
# Also creates a method called <code>name=</code> to set the attribute.
# String arguments are converted to symbols.
# 
#    module Mod
#      attr_accessor(:one, :two)
#    end
#    Mod.instance_methods.sort   #=> [:one, :one=, :two, :two=]
def attr_accessor(*several_variants)
    #This is a stub, used for indexing
end
```

となっており

**`Mod.instance_methods.sort   #=> [:one, :one=, :two, :two=]`**
の部分から、
`attr_accessor`が**末尾=メソッド**を生やしているから不要でしょう。

Answer (score 0):

```
user = User.create({:name => 'hoge', :email => 'fuga'})
```

は

```
user = User.new
user.name = 'hoge'
user.email = 'fuga'
user.save
```

などとも書けますが、Nested Attributesを使う時は後者の形式は使えない、では困るでしょう。